# Converting Tkinter py to executable file

Tags: python, tkinter, physics

I just created a probability density calculator for a particle in a box. Now i want to convert the .py file to an .exe file. I tried using pyinstaller (pyinstaller --name PartyProb --onefile --windowed --icon=psi.ico PartyProb.py) and when I click on the executable file nothing happens.
This is my calculator code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sympy import symbols, pi, evalf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def parse_position_range(position_str):
    positions = [p.strip() for p in position_str.split(',')]
    parsed_positions = []

    for pos in positions:
        try:
            parsed_positions.append(float(pos))
        except ValueError:
            parsed_positions.append(eval(pos.replace('pi', str(pi))).evalf())
    
    return parsed_positions

def probability_density_function(x, n, L):
    psi_squared = (2/L) * np.sin((n * np.pi * x) / L)**2
    return psi_squared

def calculate_probability_in_range(x_range, n, L):
    integrand = lambda x: probability_density_function(x, n, L)
    probability, _ = quad(integrand, x_range[0], x_range[1])
    return probability

def plot_probability_density(n_values, L, x_range):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))

    for n in n_values:
        x_values = np.linspace(0, L, 1000)
        psi_squared = probability_density_function(x_values, n, L)
        ax.plot(x_values, psi_squared, label=f'n={n}')

    ax.set_xlabel('Position (x)')
    ax.set_ylabel('|ψ(x)|^2')
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid(True)

    return fig

def on_calculate_probability():
    n_values = [int(n) for n in entry_n.get().split(',')]
    L = float(entry_L.get())
    x_range_str = entry_range.get()
    x_range = parse_position_range(x_range_str)

    probability_results = []
    for n in n_values:
        probability_in_range = calculate_probability_in_range(x_range, n, L)
        probability_results.append(f'P(n={n}): {probability_in_range:.4e}')

    probability_label.config(text='\n'.join(probability_results), font=('Arial', 12))

    # Plot the probability density function
    fig = plot_probability_density(n_values, L, x_range)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
    canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    canvas_widget.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Create the Tkinter root window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Particle in a Box Probability Calculator")

# Load and resize the image
image_path = r"C:\Users\jandi\Downloads\normalised_rob_density_function.png"
original_image = Image.open(image_path)
resized_image = original_image.resize((625, 100))  # Adjust the size as needed
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

# Introductory message label
intro_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Welcome to the Particle in a Box Probability Calculator!\n"
                                     "This programme calculates the probability of finding a particle in a given range in one dimension.\n"
                                     "Enter quantum numbers [1, 2, 3, ...], box width (L) [1], and position range [0 ≤ P(L) ≤ 1] to get started.\n"
                                     "Values in the position range can include pi (this format) but not fractions [1/2] (idk why). For example, [0.5*pi/2].\n"
                       "A graph of the probability density at each position will also be generated. It is similar to the text and are a combination\n" 
                       "of sine and cosine wavefunction. Interestingly, as the quantum number increases, |ψ|^2 becomes an approximation of some constant probability.\n"
                       "Enjoy P.Chem II!\n"
                        
                                                                                                                                                                    "jm\n")
intro_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Image label
image_label = ttk.Label(window, image=image)
image_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

ttk.Label(window, text="Quantum Numbers (comma-separated):").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e', padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Label(window, text="Box Width (L):").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e', padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Label(window, text="Position Range (comma-separated):").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='e', padx=5, pady=5)

entry_n = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_n.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)
entry_L = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_L.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5)
entry_range = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_range.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=5)

calculate_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Calculate Probability", command=on_calculate_probability)
calculate_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

probability_label = ttk.Label(window, text="", font=('Times New Roman', 12))
probability_label.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

This was done in jupyter notebook.

I tried the pyinstaller and the auto-py-to-exe methods but get the same error. I expect to get an executable file that could be alone.

Comment: Try converting it to a *console* application instead and execute the generated executable in a console to see any error reported. It is most likely error on missing module.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).